# Incapsulate element from page css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to encapsulate a view from page styles in the following way:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  
    *:not(.component) > button, *:not(.component) > span, *:not(.component) > p{
      background: green;
     }
    
    </style>
     
    <div class="component">
     <button>Button</button>
    
     <span>Span</span>
    
     <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
```

I would like to simplify the css above to have something like:

```
*:not(.component) > button, span, p{
            background: green;
        }
```

This applies the condition only for `button`.

Also I was wondering if this kind of 'encapsulation' will hit the performance?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you were using LESS (and probably SASS, idk) you could do something like that.  But straight CSS needs them each listed explicitly.  To my knowledge there is no way to abbreviate them like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to a little JS you can leverage [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM) which automagically scopes the markup. You may need to use a [webcomponent polyfill](https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills) depending on your target audience till it has better browser support.

```js
var shadow = document.querySelector('.component')
  .attachShadow({
    mode: 'open'
  })
shadow.innerHTML = `
    <button>Button</button>
    <span>Span</span>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
`
```

```css
p {
    background: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="component">
</div>

<div>
  <button>Button</button>
  <span>Span</span>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```